# "Date Modified" and "Date Created" fields seem to be reversed in File Explorer (Win 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, windows-explorer, metadata

I've noticed this for quite a long time on the files in my libraries (documents, pictures, videos, you name it). When I right click the details bar in a File Explorer window to view more metadata columns, the "date modified" column usually reflects the day a file first appeared on my system rather than the "date created" one and I've always wondered why that is or if there is some setting I have wrong, or perhaps it has to do with the way other apps and stuff handle those files. If they handle them differently than File Explorer does, that could explain it but Idk. All I know is this happens with most of my files on Windows, the vast majority or I would say all of them, regardless of whether I copied footage off an SD card or downloaded something from the web. Even my documents have this.

I have always wondered if this was normal or if I'm a unique case. Is it possible that this is some kind of file metadata corruption that occurred when I either went to backup files or copied all files from my backup to my current system? That is the only thing I can think of at this point. Problem is though, if that were the case then I would see "date modified" being updated whenever I rename a file or edit it's details etc. but that is not happening. Looks like the only general detail being accurately stored is the "Accessed" field.

Comment: I don't see such thing here. All dates are correct.

Comment: Could you show a practical example? (With screenshots, etc.?)

Answer (score 0):

If anybody's still wondering about this topic, I got a pretty good answer from somebody on Quora: The "date modified" field can be virtually anything depending on the source of where a file was copied from, but the "date created" field can get updated to a newer date if the file is pasted somewhere else. I suppose in my case with copying files from my archive onto newer systems, this happens quite a bit. Even if they are documents which one could edit anytime, if they haven't been edited, the created date will become newer than the modified date. Like I said, the "accessed" field more accurately reflects how I am interacting with the files. And of course, in the case of audio and video files which is where I notice this the most, the actual data on file never changes unless (possibly) if you were to overwrite it with a file of the same name, or compress the file and change its contents but not the duration, etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).